# Processing 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have xml file to read and process data. I have list of details record. My requirement is to remove records with same Number and RefNo but have positive and negative values.

**Scenario 1 : Should return 1 record**

```
<Detail>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Amount>20.0</Amount>
    <RefNo>1</RefNo>
</Detail>
```

**Scenario 2 : Should return 0 record because amount are positive and negative**

```
<Detail>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Amount>20.0</Amount>
    <RefNo>1</RefNo>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Amount>-20.0</Amount>
    <RefNo>1</RefNo>
</Detail>
```

I have achieved it by using 2 list for positive and negative values. I solved above scenarios using following code.

```
var actualRecords =
    (from detailList in positiveDetails
    where !negativeDetails.Any(x => x.Number == detailList.PolicyNo
                                 && x.RefNo == detailList. RefNo)
    select detailList).ToList();
```

But above code return zero records in following scenario.
Positive > Negative > Positive. It should return 1 record cancelling 1 positive and 1 negative record for same Number and RefNo.

I want solution for following scenarios with same Number and Ref No.

•   Positive > Negative > Positive – 1 record 
•   Positive > Negative > Positive > Negative – 0 record
•   Positive > Negative > Positive > Negative > Positive – 1 record
•   Positive > Negative > Positive > Negative > Positive > Negative  – 0 record
•   Positive > Negative > Positive > Negative > Positive > n

**Assumption**
Negative always appear after positive values. I can do this by for loops. But I’m searching for better solution.
Appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you merely aggregating the details or actually trying to match up details that cancel each other out exactly?  The former would be easier to write.

e.g., for a document that looks like this

```
<Root>
    <Details>
        <Detail>
            <Number>1</Number>
            <Amount>40.0</Amount>
            <RefNo>1</RefNo>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Number>1</Number>
            <Amount>-20.0</Amount>
            <RefNo>1</RefNo>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Number>1</Number>
            <Amount>20.0</Amount>
            <RefNo>1</RefNo>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Number>1</Number>
            <Amount>-30.0</Amount>
            <RefNo>2</RefNo>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Number>1</Number>
            <Amount>20.0</Amount>
            <RefNo>1</RefNo>
        </Detail>
    </Details>
</Root>
```

```
XDocument doc = ...;
var details = doc.XPathSelectElement("/Root/Details");
var newDetails =
    from detail in details.Elements("Detail")
    let amount = (decimal)detail.Element("Amount")
    let number = (int)detail.Element("Number")
    let refNo = (int)detail.Element("RefNo")
    // group amounts by number and refno
    group amount by new { number, refNo } into g
    let amount = g.Sum()
    // filter out completely canceled out groups
    where amount != 0M
    select new XElement("Detail",
        new XElement("Number", g.Key.number),
        new XElement("Amount", amount.ToString("N1")),
        new XElement("RefNo", g.Key.refNo)
    );
details.ReplaceAll(newDetails);
```

Yields:

```
<Root>
  <Details>
    <Detail>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Amount>60.0</Amount>
      <RefNo>1</RefNo>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Amount>-30.0</Amount>
      <RefNo>2</RefNo>
    </Detail>
  </Details>
</Root>
```

---

Otherwise, you need to match up elements that cancel each other out.  It can still be done in a single query, though a slightly more complicated one.

```
XDocument doc = ...;
var details = doc.XPathSelectElement("/Root/Details");
var newDetails =
    from detail in details.Elements("Detail")
    let amount = (decimal)detail.Element("Amount")
    let number = (int)detail.Element("Number")
    let refNo = (int)detail.Element("RefNo")
    let key = Math.Abs(amount) // cancellable amounts
    // group amounts by key, number and refno
    group amount by new { key, number, refNo } into g
    let amount = g.Sum()
    // filter out completely canceled out groups
    where amount != 0M
    let count = (int)Math.Abs(amount / g.Key.key) // how many to recreate
    let sign = Math.Sign(amount)
    // recreate uncancelled values
    from a in Enumerable.Repeat(sign * g.Key.key, count)
    select new XElement("Detail",
        new XElement("Number", g.Key.number),
        new XElement("Amount", a.ToString("N1")),
        new XElement("RefNo", g.Key.refNo)
    );
details.ReplaceAll(newDetails);
```

Yields:

```
<Root>
  <Details>
    <Detail>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Amount>40.0</Amount>
      <RefNo>1</RefNo>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Amount>20.0</Amount>
      <RefNo>1</RefNo>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <Amount>-30.0</Amount>
      <RefNo>2</RefNo>
    </Detail>
  </Details>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way could be to `GroupBy` `Number` and `RefNo` then `Count` the positive and negative `Amount` if the counts don't match then return those `Detail` elements

Something like:

```
var actualRecords = detailList.GroupBy(x => new{ x.Number, x.RefNo}) // group by Number and RefNo
                              .Where(x => x.Count(p => p.Amount > 0) // count positives
                                       != x.Count(n => n.Amount < 0)) // count negatives
                              .SelectMany(detail => detail); // contains the Details that have unequal amounts of positive and negative amounts
```